# How to find the IP of an embedded Linux device

Tags: linux, ip

I am building a small embedded Linux device, providing a simple TELNET server to the users for changing the IP address and other required configurations (no console access is available).

Should someone change the default IP address and forget the new address, how can I find the device's new address?

Is there any way of broadcasting some kind of a standard packet and receiving the device's address?

If it is required I can embed small standard packages that would leak some info and allow me to later on acquire the device's IP address.

Comment: [Use arp-scan to find hidden devices in your network](http://www.blackmoreops.com/2015/12/31/use-arp-scan-to-find-hidden-devices-in-your-network/)

Comment: You can make it respond to any kind of broadcast you want, so long as you also make a tool to send that kind of broadcast and process the response.

Answer (score 0):

Use Nmap to scan the network.  You can find the ip from there.  If there are lots of systems in your network sort out the ip by recording the other ip and removing it from the list so that you are left with ip of the embedded device.

> -Use zenmap if you need gui
>
> -Please use this only in your home network, or if you are authorized.  Otherwise it is may be illegal

Comment: That doesn't work very well if the network has a very large block of IP addresses, and it's considered antisocial on many networks.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That is true, but how can we get the ip addr of a system of which we have no access, we need some kind of scanning for that rite

Comment: Yes, just not *this* kind of scanning.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  will we get any response to ping to the broadcast address of network*.*.*.255

Comment: If the device responds to broadcast pings. That's less anti-social.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The broadcast ping was a good clue. I enabled broadcast ping and now my device responds to "ping 224.0.0.1". The point is that i know nothing about the range of the device's ip addr. so ping x.x.x.255 will not work. (I have not worked with nmap, but from what i've understood that wont help me either; pls correct me if i am wrong !?!)

Comment: Hi, again; There is another point that i should still follow: Enabling broadcast ping is considered a security hole. Is there another way (or safe standard linux service) that i can run on the machine (so it can later respond to my BROADCAST/MULTICAST probes) and help me in discovering the device? SPECIFICALLY, I THINK IF THERE WAS A L2 APP/SERVICE THAT RESPONDED TO L2 BROADCASTS/MULTICASTS, THAT WOULD BE QUITE SAFE

Comment: @david, i am new to stackexchange. How can i up vote your comment

Comment: @qwa  Nmap will work,  but it is offensive if you are not using it in your own network.  Nmap will get you more than what you need.  If you are new to nmap use zenmap it is GUI of Nmap.  Just do an intensive search and you will get all you need.